# Can you make instant changes to an opened app?

Tags: android, iphone

So not sure if what I want is possible but it probably is I just don’t know the terms for it. Anyone who can help me put it in to worlds would be an immense help!

Basically I want to make an app for young kids (7-9)  (I’m a Teacher!) to use to play tag with let’s say 4 different objects in the room.

Ideally we all have downloaded this app and have it open on our phones, I want to be able to select a object and it highlights and then is shown on all their apps and they then run to the highlighted item is the idea.

I’m not sure what terms or steps I need to do to cause updates to the app without downloading a new version or resetting the app for a flash update?

I’m somewhat experienced in UI a bit, mostly just taking information and tying it to the images is my level of experience.

this is my first foray in to any coding or backend work so looking forward to starting my first project.

Not looking for coding handed to me, just terms to go look up on my own!

I haven’t tried anything yet, except looked up as much as I could find on pushing live updates on apps. Most result’s didn’t seem promising.

The one idea I had was using Web Alert to have them all view a website and updating it with a command from my phone or a twitch stream with an image I can manipulate with commands?

Comment: An update to an app is where you make a code change, compile that change, and thus have a new version of the app with new/changed functionality. What you are talking about is totally unrelated to that, you want to transmit, presumably based on your description, an image from one device to others. If they are within range  of each other you may be able to do that using Bluetooth, otherwise you'll have to upload the image from one phone to a server, and then the server would push it to the other handsets. Regardless, not a trivial thing your talking about